# How to override collectTotals function In Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add custom value i.e custom fees in cart page bellow subtotal. so the Grand total should contain the custom fee. here i mean to say that during Quote state Grand total should contain custom fee. and from Quote to  Order State grand total must contain that custom fee.